# Count the number of license plates.

Tags: combinatorics

At the moment I deal with problems in combinatorics and I still have some questions concerning the license plate exercise.

> First, I would like to determine the number of license plates formed by 2 letters and 4 digits (repetition allowed).

My idea is to calculate $26^2 * 10^4$. But I am not sure, if this is correct, because repetitions are allowed here.

> Secondly, I am looking for the number of license plates that are formed either by 6 letters or by 6 digits (repetition allowed).

Is it correct if I just compute $26^6 + 10^6$ ?

> Finally, I want to determine the number of license plates that are formed either by 6 distinct letters or 6 distinct digits.

I calculate $\frac{26!}{20!} + \frac{10!}{4!}$.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You say repetitions are allowed, but then you say distinct letters/digits. Are there two problems here?

Comment: Yes, there are two problems or actually three :).

Comment: You can't mix digits and letters?  I think you should state the problems individually. It's very hard to understand your question as written.

Comment: @fleabood Is the question now more understandable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of ways to form license plates with 2 letters and 4 digits is $26^2 \cdot 10^4$ if repetitions are allowed.

The number of ways to form license plates with 6 distinct letters is $P(26, 6)$ or $$26\cdot 25\cdot 24\cdot 23\cdot 22\cdot 21.$$

Similarly, the number of ways to form license plates with 6 distinct numbers is $P(10, 6).$

To find the total you add (# ways to form plates with numbers) and (# ways to form plates with letters).

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Ok, then the solution to the first problem would be the same as for the problem, where I have to find number of license plates with 2 letters followed by 4 numbers.  Concerning the second problem : If the numbers and letters do not have to be distinct, I also just need to calculate $26^2 + 10^4$, right ?

Comment: Yes :) do you understand my answer?

Comment: Sure, I understand it. It was also my first approach, but I was unsure. Now I am happy that you confirmed it ;). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No.  You do not add.

If you need to find all the combinations satisfying BOTH conditions A AND condition B, you *multiply* the number of ways to do A by the number of ways to do B.

If you need find all the combinations satisfying ONE of condition A OR condition B then you *add* the numbers of ways of each.

To make this clear consider making a licence plate with two characters.  The first is either a,b, or c (we'll call that condition A) and the second is 1,2,3,  or 4 (we'll call that condition B).

We want the plate to have BOTH conditions.  So the options are:  a1,b1,c1 or a2,b2,c2, or a3,b3,c3 or a4,b4,c4.

I hope it is clear that each plate having one of  3 letter options AND one of 4 numbers options is $3\times 4$ options total.

But if we want the licence to have EITHER condition A OR condition B, then the options are a,b, or c, or 1,2,3 or 4.

I hope it's clear that if you need one of 3 letter options OR one of 4 number options is $3+4$ options total.

=====

It's not the allowing or disallowing distinct terms that determine if you add or multiply.  That has NOTHING to do with it.

It's the requiring two conditions in one outcome vs. having one condition or a completely different condition that determines if you add or multiply.

===

So

1) a licence has two letters AND four digits (such as RT3213) there are $26^2*10^4$ ways.

2) A licence has two letters OR four digits (so RT is okay and 3123 is okay but RT3213 is NOT) there are $26^2+10^4$ ways.

3) a license  plate has two distinct letters AND four distinct numbers there are $(26*25)*(10*9*8*7) $ ways.

4) two distinct letters OR four distinct numbers there are $26*25+10*9*8*7$ ways.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. You really have taught me in combinatorics. Great !